# Denormalization of output from neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, normalization

I have used the MinMax normalization in order to normalize my dataset, both features and label. My question is, it's correct to normalize also the label? If yes, how can I denormalize the output of the neural network (the one that I predict with the test set that is normalized)?

I can't upload the dataset, but it is composed by 18 features and 1 label. It is a regression task, the features and the label are physical quantities.

So the problem is that the `y_train_pred` and `y_test_pred` are between 0 and 1. How can I predict the "real value"?

The code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv', decimal=',', delimiter = ";")

label = dataset.iloc[:,-1]
features = dataset.drop(columns = ['Label'])

features = features[best_features]

X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(features, label, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 1, shuffle = True)

y_test2 = y_test1.to_frame()
y_train2 = y_train1.to_frame()

scaler1 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler1.fit_transform(X_train1)
X_test = scaler2.fit_transform(X_test1)

scaler3 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler4 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_train = scaler3.fit_transform(y_train2)
y_test = scaler4.fit_transform(y_test2)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.001)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(80, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(120, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(80, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 300,
                    validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=False,   batch_size=120
                    )
history_dict = history.history

loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']

y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: It's quite strange to normalize labels (unless these are continuous targets). Is there any particular reason to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should denormalize so you can get real world predictions to your neural network, rather than a number between 0-1

The min - max normalization is defined by:

```
z = (x - min)/(max - min)
```

With z being the normalized value, x being the label value, max being the max x value, and min being the min x value. So if we have z, min, and max we can resolve for x as follows:

```
x = z(max - min) + min
```

Thus before you normalize your data, define variables for the max and min value for the label if it is continuous. Then after you get your pred values, you can use the following function:

```
y_max_pre_normalize = max(label)
y_min_pre_normalize = min(label) 

def denormalize(y):
    final_value = y(y_max_pre_normalize - y_min_pre_normalize) + y_min_pre_normalize 
    return final_value
```

And apply this function to your y_test/y_pred to get the corresponding value.

[You can use this link here to better visualize this.](https://martinfournier.com/how-to-normalize-and-denormalize-data-between-0-and-1/)

Comment: I understand what you say, but the maximum and minimum values of my outoput (y_predict) aren't equal to the maximum and minimum values of label. So, in my opinion, I can't use your code line because the max and min that you evaluate is refered to the label and not to the "denormalized" predicted values that comes from the neural network. What do you think about?

Comment: When you apply min max to your label you are applying to based off your label values and not your feature values. Thus your label values are independent of your feature values, and you can use the min max of the original labels (in your code label = dataset.iloc[:,-1]) to determine what min and max to use. This is how MinMaxScaler() normalizes it in the first place so I don't understand why you can't use it again.

Comment: You need to get the min max before you do the MinMaxScaler() in the label function. And then treat the output in y_test/y_pred as the z value in the function above. We aren't using the min max of y_predict but the Min Max of labels, the original independent variable. The values in y_pred are your z values

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I am also struggling with the same problem. I am still not quite sure why this answer is correct, from my understanding when you get your predicted y values, they will have a max and min values that are different than the actual/original y values, no? Can anyone clarify this?